# Is it possible to programmatically set the state of the shift and control keys?

Tags: keyboard

The reason I am asking is that I am thinking of building a foot switch to act as shift and control keys - well two switches, one for each foot.

I'm planning on using the [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) for this and writing a small C# application to detect when the switch has been pressed that would then set the state of shift or control. I would rather not have to write a keyboard driver for the Arduino as I would like it to do other things as well.

Comment: +1 Excellent idea, even more useful if the pedal/key allocations were programmable to help if someone had restricted use of one hand - or for gaming!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you will have to pInvoke out to Win32. Have a look at the [keydb_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html) call.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
```

You can then call:

```
keybd_event(0x10, 0, 0, 0);
```

to turn on the shift key (ie. key down), and:

```
keybd_event(0x10, 0, 2, 0);
```

to turn it off again (ie. key up).

The first argument is the hex value of the key to press:

- 0x10 = shift
- 0x11 = ctrl
- 0x12 = alt

I've just tried this in a simple C# application using a checkbox to represent the shift key. With it checked, it "held" the shift key in for any application I used.

Comment: It is safer to work with try-finally, so that the shift key is released in any case: `ShiftKeyDown(); try { RunSomeCode(); } finally { ShiftKeyUp(); }`. I usually do the same when setting the wait cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in controlling the foreground application, the easiest solution is to send WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages to the active application for the press and release of your pedal.

I could be mistaken (and wiser heads, feel free to correct me if I am!) but I believe that to create an *actual* system-level keypress event -- e.g. to make *Windows* create the keydown/keyup messages for you and work correctly even if you change applications while the pedal is held down -- you need to write an input driver.